# Using cURL for a large request

Tags: php, curl, pear

I'm trying to build a reliable mailing system which is causing me some trouble and generally not being very reliable.

I currently have a dedicated server which has a couple of php scripts setup to add mails to be sent to a MySQL db using PEAR mail_queue and another to send them off using PEAR and a cron job. This all works well.

The bit that i'm struggling with is filling the database without bringing down the site that the newsletters are being sent from.

The newsletter are setup and sent from an admin panel on the backend of the site, held on a shared server. When the send newsletter button is clicked it sends a cURL request to the dedicated server to fill the db. However, when sending a newsletter with 600+ subscribers the whole site stalls and it doesn't return until the process has finished - which it does at least do.

How do I setup a cURL or other request that can run in the background or asynchronously or whatever that doesn't kill the site?

here's some code:

```
$hCurl = curl_init();

$curl_options = array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_POST => true, CURLOPT_URL => "http://DOMAIN/PATH/SCRIPT", CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "VARIABLE TO SEND");

curl_setopt_array($hCurl, $curl_options);

$sResp = curl_exec($hCurl);
curl_close($hCurl);
```

the script this runs adds the subscribers to the mail_queue after checking they're valid emails and returns a status and any invalid emails. I guess adding 600+ emails to a MySQL db is a lot of work for this to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that cURL request supposed to start a remote script which in turns sends out the mails? The cURL functions anyway cannot themselves initiate a background process. You might have luck with something like `exec("nohup curl http://www/ &")` for starting an unattended side job.

Comment: thanks for the response. the cURL request is to fill a db with mails to be sent out - the emails are then sent out at intervals using a cron job to help reduce the load on the smtp server - which was one part of the problem. I'll have to have a look at exec() to see if it'll help with a background process.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you could probably fork (although I'm not sure that works outside CLI). However, even if that did work, it would probably be more hassle than it's worth, seeing as you could hardly debug the thing if you're running under Apache. So your best bet would probably be to serialize whatever data you need to pass on, dump it to a file, and call another php script with exec() which then processes the serialized data and performs the rest of the magic asynchronously. Of course, the script call would have to push it in the background, and you would have to pass the name of the file containing the serialized data.

A crude skeleton would look something like this:

```
$fname=tempnam("/tmp","curl_");
$fp=fopen($fname,'w');
fputs($fp,serialize("VARIABLE TO SEND"));
fclose($fp);
exec("php do_the_curly.php $fname &");
```

where do_the_curly.php would bascially contain the code in your original script, with the bit about reading the serialized data prepended to it.